# Displaying Only Top Level Solver Convergence Information in pyCycle Afterburning Turbojet Example

Tags: openmdao

I am running the afterburning_turbojet.py example in pyCycle. The solver settings are set in the following way:

```
prob.set_solver_print(level=-1)
prob.set_solver_print(level=2, depth=1)
```

From my understanding of the docs, these settings would suppress all solver convergence information except for the top level solver.

https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/core_features/controlling_solver_behavior/solver_options.html

When running this example, I do not see any Solver Convergence information in the output.

I changed the second solver print line to have a depth = 2 as follows:
`prob.set_solver_print(level=2, depth=2)`

After running with this new setting, I get two levels of solver convergence information as expected. The output for the DESIGN condition is shown below:

```
======
DESIGN
======
+  
+  ===========
+  DESIGN.nozz
+  ===========
+  NL: Newton 0 ; 5.17247638 1
+  |  LS: BCHK 0 ; 394.213636 76.2137141
+  NL: Newton 1 ; 1.06843454 0.206561511
+  |  LS: BCHK 0 ; 2.11020074 1.97503981
+  NL: Newton 2 ; 0.067817265 0.0131111793
+  |  LS: BCHK 0 ; 4.87296497 71.8543423
+  NL: Newton 3 ; 0.00031009478 5.99509321e-05
+  |  LS: BCHK 0 ; 6.54581749e-09 2.11090864e-05
+  NL: Newton 4 ; 6.54300782e-09 1.26496621e-09
+  |  LS: BCHK 0 ; 9.600448e-11 0.0146728359
+  NL: Newton 5 ; 2.41002626e-15 4.65932771e-16
+  NL: Newton Converged
NL: Newton 0 ; 141.291478 1
+  
+  ===========
+  DESIGN.nozz
+  ===========
+  NL: Newton 0 ; 0.000238211558 1
+  |  LS: BCHK 0 ; 3.86546222e-09 1.62270137e-05
+  NL: Newton 1 ; 3.86116435e-09 1.62089715e-05
+  |  LS: BCHK 0 ; 9.22046162e-11 0.023880003
+  NL: Newton 2 ; 5.6397377e-16 2.36753319e-12
+  NL: Newton Converged
NL: Newton 1 ; 0.490454473 0.00347122472
+  
+  ===========
+  DESIGN.nozz
+  ===========
+  NL: Newton 0 ; 6.15958868e-09 1
+  |  LS: BCHK 0 ; 6.55028133e-11 0.0106342837
+  NL: Newton 1 ; 1.60080391e-15 2.59888118e-07
+  NL: Newton Converged
NL: Newton 2 ; 0.000888988351 6.29187521e-06
+  
+  ===========
+  DESIGN.nozz
+  ===========
+  NL: Newton 0 ; 3.34459206e-15 1
+  NL: Newton Converged
NL: Newton 3 ; 7.88782356e-07 5.5826605e-09
NL: Newton Converged
```

I would like to only have the top level output. What settings should I use to suppress the "DESIGN.nozz" newton solver output? From what I can tell, this seems to only be a problem with the afterburning turbojet example. For the other examples, setting the depth=2 seems to output what I want.

As well, for my understanding, does the set_solver_print call override any iprint options that were set for the newton solver in the ABTurbojet() class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the N2 for the example you're running. The level number is relative to the top of the model. Your last call set the solver print level to 1 at a depth of 2. That went down to the nozzle level (the second level).

You can manually adjust the [solver print level](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.26.0/features/building_blocks/solvers/newton.html#newtonsolver-options) of any specific solver via

```
<path>.<to>.<solver>.options['iprint'] = <something>
```

The helper methods are just blunt instruments. If you're not getting exactly what you want, just adjust the print levels manually.